# Why several Pie Charts are being merged into one? MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to show 3 several pie charts on the same layout. I insert different data sets to different charts, but by the end all of these data shows on 1 chart and **another 2 charts have no data**.
Could there be a problem that I cannot create several charts on one layout?

```
private PieChart firstCh, secondCh, thirdCh;
private void openDialog() {

    //code with dialog

        firstCh = dialogStat.findViewById(R.id.firstCharacter);
        secondCh = dialogStat.findViewById(R.id.secondCharacter);
        thirdCh = dialogStat.findViewById(R.id.thirdCharacter);

        ArrayList<PieEntry> statForFirst = new ArrayList<>();
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Kiss"));
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Marry"));
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Kill"));

        ArrayList<PieEntry> statForSecond = new ArrayList<>();
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Kiss"));
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Marry"));
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Kill"));

        ArrayList<PieEntry> statForThird = new ArrayList<>();
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Kiss"));
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Marry"));
        statForFirst.add(new PieEntry(myNumber, "Kill"));

        setNewChart(firstCh, statForFirst);
        setNewChart(secondCh, statForSecond);
        setNewChart(thirdCh, statForThird);

        //code with dialog
    }

private void setNewChart(PieChart chart, ArrayList<PieEntry> entries) {
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
        dataSet.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.pinkySarah), getResources().getColor(R.color.lightViola), getResources().getColor(R.color.eyeKiller));

        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        data.setDrawValues(true);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(chart));
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setValueTextColor(R.color.darkViola);

        chart.setData(data);
    chart.invalidate();
    }
```

[This is how it looks in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0RnF.jpg)
For reference, i am using LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo mistake.

you have added all the data to statForFirst arraylist instead of other two lists. Fix this and you are good to go